# Choosing the correct prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Is the preposition "at" suitable in this sentence:

> Let's spend the whole day ***at*** the beach?

Comment: I would say "**on** the beach"

Comment: You can use either ***at*** or ***on*** in your context. Note that ***at*** can be less "precise" here - it's more suitable if you mean *the general area where the beach is* (perhaps sitting in a beachside cafe all afternoon), where ***on** the beach* more specifically refers to actually being at the shoreline (sunbathing on the sand, for example). Thus if the speaker has just got up in his seafront holiday apartment, he'd more likely use ***on***, but his friends who are thinking of driving over from some inland town to meet up with him might be more likely to use ***at***.

Comment: As @FumbleFingers says, *at* nudges the interpretation in the *location* direction (i.e., the beach is conceptualized as a single point), whereas *on* is more literal.

Comment: You could also say **by** the beach if you want to include "in the water" and other nearby areas . . .

Answer (score 1):

In your example, using

> **at**
>   is perfectly fine to designate a location or place.
>
> **at** the beach
>   **at** the supermarket
>   **at** the races
>   **at** my friend's house

Comment: And let's not forget [_at the movies_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_the_Movies_(U.S._TV_series))...